# English word combination to translate a Persian poetic word “DelGard”

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I’m looking for one word or a two English word combination to translate one Persian poetic word DelGard - Del meaning Heart and Gard meaning Wanderer. I couldnt find anything in dictionary. This word is a poetic word, hard to get the equivalent in English.

Are the following expressions correct:

> Heart Rover
> Heart traveller
> Heart Wanderer
> Heart Vagrant
> Heart Drifter

The word DelGard is alliteration to the word VelGard meaning a homeless, traveller, vagrant or vagabond. The word DelGard in Persian describes a person who is roaming around, and who has no home, travel from place to place based on the wisdom of his/her heart, he/she is the seeker of love and follows his/her intuition or heart (in positive sense). Heart is symbol of pure love which unites human souls.

Comment: You also may not want to directly translate "heart" because by itself it doesn't communicate a specific meaning in English. Please explain as best you can what the Persian word communicates to the reader/listener. Then we can give English suggestions that don't just translate, but also communicate the same meaning/feeling.

Comment: Please supply a sentence where your sought-for word is used.

Answer (score 1):

A person who does whatever their intuition tells them might be called a [free spirit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-spirit). It doesn't necessarily mean that they wander, although they might. It has a sense of being a non-conformist and not worrying too much about what other people think of you. It is a pretty positive/approving word in AmE.

> The Irishman was a **free spirit**, a wild rover who would not be tied down. ([*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-spirit))

> Whenever you feel the evil influence of the middle class muddling your soul, you'll say these two words and you'll be a **free spirit** again: "Isadora Duncan." ([*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Isadora_Duncan))

Answer (score 1):

How about a 'troubadour'? This is somebody who wanders around, usually with musical, poetic, and inherently, romantic, intentions.

Many similar words that you'll find at this link may also do - balladeer, minstrel, bard.

You could express it poetically, like: 'his minstrel's heart led him to travel, stumbling around, discovering and finding love, as he did so...'

Or, 'his troubadour's heart guided him on many travelling adventures or a romantic kind...'

Troubadour is a great word because it does imply ronance, adventure, misadventure... always with a kind of..lyrical romantic hopefulness!

It is the heart that guides the Troubadour - who is pretty much homeless - he travels from place to place, earning board and lodgings mostly for his ad hoc recitations of songs or poetry.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=troubadour+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

You could borrow 'the fool' from the tarot cards for this archetype, also.

You could also use 'gypsy' - you could talk about 'his wandering, gypsy soul...' for example. Or say his heart was like a gypsy...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a literal translation, heart wanderer would be just as good as any that you mentioned.  However, I would encourage you to take a little liberty with that definition.

May I suggest using the word wanderlust, which probably means something very similar.

> wanderlust ˈwɒndəlʌst/ noun - a strong desire to travel.

Comment: Thanks Neil, the word actually refers to person who travel to seek love and unity... a roamer who not purly desire to travel but also to seek love and his/her love and intuition... (love more in spiritual and positive sense)

Comment: @Maryam Well it is often used in a spiritual sense in english as well.  You wouldn't call a businessman who travels on business often someone with wanderlust.  It is more about growth and seeing the world.  I'm not sure if love fits in that definition, but I would argue that that definition is fairly close.

Comment: Really appreciate yr suggestion.. there is a sense of homelessness and being vagrant in the Persian word, a Wanderer who instead of searching for food or home / money, is traveling from place to place to seek love... there is less emphasis on the desire to travell but the aim is to find love

Comment: @Maryam Then heart wanderer should be sufficient.  It is still a little vague (because no precise term exists), but it renders the idea well enough I think.

Comment: Thx Neil, I guess the Heart Wanderer convey the meaning better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You yourself used "seeker" when describing the word.  That sounds like the best choice here.  Or "soul-searcher".